# How does Minecraft have a .exe extension on windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, exe, minecraft

I've always wondered how, on Windows, Minecraft has an exe file that will work, You can also change the file extension to .jar and run it like a normal jar file as well, Any ideas on how they have accomplished this?
I've searched all over google and haven't found any answers. Unless I'm just searching the wrong thing, I would like to know how to package my JARs like this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

They use a program called launch4J to wrap the jar into an exe.  As you can see the program here http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/.  This is apparent when you run minecraft with No java installed you will see a message box from launch4j saying that you need to install java.  Note the java code is not converted to native windows code just launched natively.